# what's the correct way to find out flask's endpoint by function name?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, access-control, blueprint

I have a flask demo, and it needs access control. My access control is base on function name, and I wrote a decorator to do it.

The decorator define is:

```
def permission(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wraped(*args, **kwargs):
        if _do_validate(fn.__name__):  # TODO do check user has privileges here
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)
    return wraped
```

Usage example as follow:

```
    @app.route('/index')
    @permission
    def index():
        return 'hello world'
```

This work fine if user don't specify a endpoint, because Flask's default endpoint is `fn.__name__`, in my example the `endpoint='index'`.

But when user specify a endpoint, or just use the blueprint, the endpoint was changed. For example:

```
    bl = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

    @bl.route('hello')
    @permission
    def hello():
        return 'hello world in blueprint'
```

The endpoint is changed to `admin.hello`.

I don't want to specify any arg in `@permission`, so a I write a new permission decorator as follow:

```
def permission(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wraped(*args, **kwargs):
        m = fn.__module__.split('.')
        if len(m) <= 2:
            # app must define in the root module, so if user not use blueprint, juse use fn.__name__ as endpoint
            reg_f = fn.__name__
        else:
            # blue print must define in the submodule
            reg_f = '{0}.{1}'.format(m[1], fn.__name__)

        if _do_validate(ref_f):  # TODO do check user has privileges here
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)
    return wraped
```

The problem is solved, but I think it's not elegant.

Can anyone give me a better one? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not valid in case of blueprint's name is not equal to module's `__name__`.

I can propose the next solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
registered = defaultdict(int)

def permission(fn):
    registered[fn.__name__] += 1
    fn.permission_token = "%s.%s" % (fn.__name__, registered[fn.__name__])

    @wraps(fn)
    def wraped(*args, **kwargs):
        if _do_validate(fn.permission_token):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)
    return wraped

@permission
def foo():
    pass

@permission
def bar():
    pass

def _do_validate(permission_token):
    return {foo.permission_token: True,
            bar.permission_token: False}.get(permission_token, False)
```

The main drawback of it is that you have to import all your routes in the 
`_do_validate`'s module to create such "access control list".

**UPD:** Ok, because of you want to use endpoint values to check user access, the next solution allows to find endpoint by view function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from flask import current_app

def find_endpoint(fn):
    # This loop can be optimized by maintaining
    # {permission_token => endpoint} dict.
    for endpoint, view_func in current_app.view_functions.items():
        if getattr(view_func, 'permission_token', None) == fn.permission_token:
            return endpoint
    return None

registered = defaultdict(int)

def permission(fn):
    registered[fn.__name__] += 1

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        endpoint = find_endpoint(wrapped)
        assert endpoint is not None
        if _do_validate(endpoint):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            abort(401)

    # This will work because flask's route decorator returns
    # an original view function, not the wrapped one.
    wrapped.permission_token = "%s.%s" % (fn.__name__, registered[fn.__name__])
    return wrapped

def _do_validate(endpoint):
    # Or search in the DB
    return {'index': True,
            'bp.index': False}.get(endpoint, False)
```

However, checking access by endpoint is not so good idea, because any code change during a development process could lead to undesired losing (or even worse - retrieving!) an access. So, for now my opinion is that using an extra `action` (or `resource`) argument for the `permission` decorator will be reasonable. With such parameter you can freely modify your endpoints/view functions without any undesired side effects.

**UPD2:** Actually, the much more simple way to find an endpoint value into a wrapper function is just use `request.endpoint`.

Comment: I don't want to write any code when a function need validate except `@permission`. In your solution the function's `permission_token` is mutable when app restart. Actually I have to save the `permission_token` to database, and do a   RBAC(role based access control).

Comment: @andrefun, I've updated my answer. Please, look at UPD section.

Comment: "So, for now my opinion is that using an extra action (or resource) argument for the permission decorator will be reasonable." This is the best solution ~~